# How to emit a custom sound on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-audio

I'm working on a game where a proximity detection for nearby objects will take a great role. I'd like to have it emit a sound when getting close to the obstacle - a sound of a custom tone / volume... I could probably prepare samples of sounds for that, but a custom sound of a custom tone and volume for each of the earphone played.

Answer (score 1):

See the OpenAL wrapper sound manager [HERE.](http://www.71squared.com/2011/01/latest-sound-manager/)

That allows you to set the actual position of the sound, which will affect the volume in a 3 dimensional way.